# uncaught typeerror: $(...)[0].css is not a function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to change first li test, but it is giving me typeerror

```js
$("li")[0].css("color", "orange");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Candy</li>
  <li>Fruits</li>
  <li>Chocolate</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can use `.eq(0)` to get the jQuery object

Comment: Okay! but why downvote ?

Comment: $("li")[0] also gives first element, then why can't I use .css() API on $("li")[0]

Comment: Because $("li")[0] returns a native HTML element. See my answer for the code example :)

Comment: `$("li")[0]` returns the native `<li>` element which would be identical to `document.querySelector('li')` BUT native elements don't have a `css()` method, that is a jQuery object method

Answer (score 4):

JQuery uses its own structures, so you cannot use square brackets to get the first element and then keep using JQuery instructions as it returns a native HTML element.

You should use `.first()` instead to get the first element (or `.eq(i)` to the the `i` element)

```js
$("li").first().css("color", "orange");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Candy</li>
  <li>Fruits</li>
  <li>Chocolate</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to mix JQuery with native HTML (not recommended) you could with this:

```js
$("li")[0].style.color = "orange";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Candy</li>
  <li>Fruits</li>
  <li>Chocolate</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your first statement is very misleading as `$(selector)[0]` does indeed return a native element assuming there is a matching selector

Answer (score 0):

Try with below, please specify 1,2,3,... n number to select specific li element

```
$( "ul li:nth-child(1)" ).css("color", "orange");
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work...

```js
 var item2 = $( "li.item-2" );
 $( "ul" ).find( item2 ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="item-1">Candy</li>
    <li class="item-2">Fruits</li>
    <li class="item-3">Chocolate</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```